# Tumblr: Avatar request returns not URL

Tags: ios, tumblr, mknetworkkit

I use `MKNetwork Kit` for this.

```
MKNetworkOperation *op = [[MKNetworkOperation alloc] initWithURLString:@"http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/my_blog.tumblr.com/avatar/512"
                                                                        params:nil
                                                                    httpMethod:@"GET"];

        [op addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {
            UIImage *img = [completedOperation responseImage];
            DLog(@"%f x %f", img.size.height, img.size.width); //512 x 512
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSData *myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:@"/Users/Mac/Desktop/myimage.png" contents:img attributes:nil];
        } errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation, NSError *error) {
            DLog(@"error: %@",error);
        }];

   [self enqueueOperation:op];
```

And! Oh! wonderful Tumblr! I have an Image on my Desktop.

How can I prevent this behavior and change response to json with field `avatar_url`?

UPD:

Try this:

curl http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/my_blog.tumblr.com/avatar/512

And it will returns

```
{"meta":{"status":301,"msg":"Found"},"response":{"avatar_url":"good_link_here"}}
```

UPD 2:

[Good answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tumblr-api/NYcPY2BBJE8)
I must stop redirection.

Comment: What do you by 'take url'?

Comment: json with url, I am not correct here

Comment: @rckoenes `curl` with the same url returns json with `avatar_url`

Comment: the `http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/my_blog.tumblr.com/avatar/512` is the URL to avatar!

Comment: Try an add: `Accept:application/json` header to the call.